# Expand an R data frame structure that contains a CSV value

Tags: r

I have a data frame with two columns that is modeling a dependency graph. The `source` is an Integer and the `target` contains a comma-separated string that represents the dependency.

```
1 -> "2, 3"
2 -> "4"
```

I want to expand the above data structure into an adjacency list like this:

```
1 -> 2
1 -> 3
2 -> 4
```

Comment: Do you have a dataframe or a graph???

Comment: `df%>%mutate(target = strsplit(target,','))%>%unnest`

Comment: I have a dataframe and am trying to build a data structure that represent the edges to that eventually I can send it over to ggnet2

Comment: unnest was exactly the function I was looking for, thanks @Onyambu

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data frame shown in the Note at the end:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF2 <- DF %>% separate_rows(target, convert = TRUE)

DF2
##   source target
## 1      1      2
## 2      1      3
## 3      2      4

library(igraph)

DF2 %>% graph_from_data_frame %>% plot
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

```
Lines <- 'source target
1 "2, 3"
2 "4"'
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```